# Does drawing a card end your whole turn, or just prevent further movement?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Could you continue to use items or make rolls after drawing a card, since these don't involve movement? Based on the rulebook, I think the answer is no, but I'm not sure.

From the rulebook, page 3:

> "You can perform actions (such as using an item or attacking) **in the middle of your movement.** However, whenever a game effect makes you draw a card, for any reason, **you must stop moving** for the rest of your turn.

At first I was latching on to the phrase, "you must stop moving," thinking that meant you couldn't enter more rooms, but you could still do other things. I think we even played that if we created a room that contained an item for our haunt, we could immediately take that item when we created the room. But now I see that it says you perform actions "in the middle of your movement," which makes it sound like you can't do anything after your movement ends. So if you created a room with a haunt-specific item tile in it, you wouldn't be able to pick it up in the same turn?

For another example, if you placed the vault room and drew a card, you couldn't immediately try to enter the vault on that same turn, correct?

### If actions can only occur in the middle of movement, does that mean you can't do anything else after running out of movement?

In that case, it would follow that if you were to move as far as your speed could take you, you couldn't then attack or use items or make a roll when you got there, right? Because it wouldn't be in the middle of your movement.

That doesn't seem right to me. It seems like, for instance, if you had a speed of 3, and there was an item pile three rooms away, you should be able to get to the room and then pick up the items there. Or if you had to make a skill roll three rooms away, you should be able to go there and make that roll.

So I'm wondering if I'm misunderstanding what it means by "the middle of your movement." Any insight is appreciated.

### Can you roll for event cards immediately after you've drawn them, or would you have to wait a turn?

I'm specifically wondering about the closet door event card in this regard. That card says:

> Put the closet token in the room.
>
> Once during an explorer's turn, that explorer can roll two dice to open the closet...

So, with this card, do you simply place the closet and then end your turn, or can you roll for the closet items? This is similar to the scenario with the vault, but it's different since rolling for the closet could count as part of the card event.

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! If you have multiple questions, you should ask them separately.

Comment: I believe that the part questions were connected enough to justify being posted as a single question, and I've edited the question to better clarify the connection.

Comment: You've quoted the relevant part yourself: "you must stop moving for the rest of your turn". There wouldn't be a "rest of your turn" if that was supposed to end it!

Comment: For the closet: you could roll for it after you've placed it and again at the start of your next turn.

Answer (score 7):

**You can take any other action, even though you're not allowed to move anymore.**

The keyword you are missing in the rules you quote is "can":

> You **can** perform actions (such as using an item or attacking) in the middle of your movement.

This is simply clarifying that it is allowed to do actions in the middle of movement, it is not a restriction that they can **only** be done then. You can also do actions before or after movement.

See the rules that allow other actions, on page 4 of [the rulebook](http://upload.snakesandlattes.com/rules/b/BetrayalattheHouseontheHill.pdf):

> ON YOUR TURN . . .
>
> … you can do as many of the following actions as you want, **in any order**:
>
> > • You can move.
> >
> > • You can discover a new room.
> >
> > • You can attempt a die roll.
> >
> > • You can use items or omen cards.
> >
> > • You can attack (once during your turn after the haunt starts)

This means that with things like closet and vault, you can attempt to access them immediately. Same goes for attacking after moving as far as you can.

The only thing that drawing a card or running out of movement points prevents is moving.

Comment: I was playing this the other day and I'm pretty sure I saw a rule that explicitly stated that you could do things after your movement was done. It might be useful to cite that rule too.

Comment: The exception is that there are a few cards that force (e.g. Ghost in the Machine) or allow (e.g. Secret Passage) you to move as part of resolving the card.

Comment: Forced movement is not a move action

Answer (score 1):

From the 2nd edition rulebook **Drawing Event, Item, and Omen Cards** section (pg. 10):

> Even though your movement ends when you draw a card, you can still
>   take other actions on that turn (such as using an item).